# Как применить стили?

Tags: javascript, css

есть такой js

```
$("#input-name").mouseover(function () {
 $('#input-name').attr('placeholder','Текст');
});
$("#input-name").mouseout(function() {
 $('#input-name').attr('placeholder','Имя');
});
```

при mouseover мне нужно изменить стиль плейсхолдера, можно ли это как то сделать?

Comment: Необязательно создавать новый вопрос, это можно уточнить в старом. Тем более я ответил на вашу проблему

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Рекомендуемый способ: прописать заранее заданный стиль в *css* и потом добавлять или удалять этот класс (или что вы пропишите) в элемент:

```js
$("#input-name").mouseover(function () {
    $('#input-name').attr('placeholder','Текст').addClass('hover');
});

$("#input-name").mouseout(function() {
    $('#input-name').attr('placeholder','Имя').removeClass('hover');
});
```

```css
#input-name.hover {
  border:  1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="input-name" />
```

Comment: это то, что нужно, но почему то не срабатывает у меня

Comment: @Victoria Pisareva, потому что JQ надо подключать к файлу

Comment: подключен давно

Comment: @VictoriaPisareva Я не телепат, я не знаю что у вас за код, что за стили, что за классы, что за ошибка и т.д.)) Как видите способ работает. Просто нужно смотреть что вы сделали не так))

Comment: @Victoria Pisareva, насчёт стилизации вам ответили в предыдущей теме

Comment: как сделать кроссбраузерно? в хроме работает все, а уже в мозиле при наведении текст съезжает

Comment: @Victoria_Pisareva попробуйте  *border:  1px solid red;*   заменить на *border:  1px solid red !important;*

Comment: Не `attr`, а `prop`.

Comment: @Qwertiy у ТС `attr`. Может ТС это нужно, я не в курсе. Так что не вижу смысла менять

Comment: @СергейМишин, ну так у него неправильно))

Answer (score 1):

для начала приведем наши функции в порядок *mouseover* и *mouseout*,
для того что бы достучаться до элемента из функций и добавим аргумент **e** `function ( e )`
и сохраняем наш элемент в переменную  ***JQueryEvent***

```
JQueryEvent = e.target;
```

далее в JQuery есть такое понятие как цепочки вызова функций `.mouseover().mouseout()` вот итог

```
$("#input-name")

        .mouseover( function ( e ) {

            JQueryEvent = e.target;
            $(JQueryEvent)
              .attr('placeholder','Текст')
              .css({borderColor: 'red'})

        })

        .mouseout( function ( e ) {

            JQueryEvent = e.target;
            $(JQueryEvent)
                .attr('placeholder','Имя')
                .css({borderColor: ''})

        });
```

а так же с помощью добавления классов *( рекомендуемый вариант )*

```js
$("#input-name")

                .mouseover( function ( e ) {

                    JQueryEvent = e.target;
                    $(JQueryEvent).attr('placeholder','Текст')
                        .addClass('active')

                })

                .mouseout( function( e ) {

                    JQueryEvent = e.target;
                    $(JQueryEvent).attr('placeholder','Имя')
                        .removeClass('active')

                });
```

```css
#input-name.active {
       border-color: red !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>stack</title>
</head>
<body>
<label>
    <input type="text" id="input-name">
</label>

<script>
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: для того, **чтобы**, достучат**Ь**ся и ц**Е**почки. По поводу кода: не стоит оперировать стилями непосредственно в коде. Это плохой стиль